# Notepad++ regular expression replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace `get_option('any_letter_number')` with `$options_css['any_letter_number']` In Notepad++, I can match what I need with `get_option\('.*?'\)` but replacing it with `$options_css\['.*?'\]` doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regex replacement, you use `$1` to refer to a captured subpattern.

```
get_option\('(.*?'\)
// replace with:
$options_css['$1']
```

Comment: Just for future reference, Notepad++ uses `\1` instead of `$1`.