# Regular Expression Notepad++ replace

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm trying to replace only the 'remove' strings in this block of code:

```
<table asldkjf>
remove
remove
remove
<tr>
```

The problem is keeping the 'asldkjf' string within the table tag.

I've tried replacing

```
<table[^>]*>[^<]*<tr>
```

with

```
<table[^>]*><tr>
```

And I got

```
<table[^>]*><tr>
```

Which is incorrect as it replaced the 'asldkjf' with '[^>]*'

I've tried replacing based on [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637877/notepad-regular-expression-replace)

```
<table[^>]*>[^<]*<tr>
```

with

```
<table$1><tr>
```

And I got

```
<table><tr>
```

Which is also incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing group and surround the pattern, whose text you want to use in the replacement. You can refer to them with `$n`, where n is the number of the capturing group.

For more information about how capturing group works, [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517689/confused-about-matcher-group-in-java-regex/16582083#16582083).

Find what:

```
(<table[^>]*>)[^<]*(<tr>)
```

Replace with:

```
$1$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this reegx

```
(?<=<table asldkjf>).*(?=<tr>)
```

and replace with empty string. Use dotall modifier.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/nJ6hT4/1)